# How to run powershell in jenkins with admin privileges. I just want to stop tomcat service without passing any .ps1/.bat file

Tags: powershell, jenkins

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { 
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; 
  exit 
}
```

I have followed the above script which requires to pass a .ps1 file. But I dont have access to this Jenkins hosted machine to create ps1 file and pass it.

Is there any way i can pass a Stop-Service Tomcat in this script?

Comment: Assuming your script works as-is in jenkins, you can replace `-File "$foo"` with `-Command Stop-Service Tomcat`

Comment: It worked thank you very much. But it would be great if it wont prompt for click ok to run as admin

Comment: For that, the Jenkins service itself needs to run as administrator.